# Personalize Text Wallpaper

Tags: customization, wallpaper

Anyone came across a android application (preferably Gingerbread, 2.3) that allow you to set personalize *Nice* text as your wallpaper? (I know there are some not nice application around) I search for Android market but most of the application displays clock, temperature, weather, etc which I don't really want. I saw someone on the train having their own customized word on their phone which is kind of Co0l!

Much Thanks!

Comment: Do you want text that changes in some way, or just some static text that doesn't change?

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is static text that doesn't change in any way, then by far the easiest way is to open your wallpaper image in an imaging editing program either on a PC (something as simple as Windows Paint would do) or on the phone (search the Android Market for something like "image editor" or "photo editor" and you should find lots of apps that can do this like [PicSay](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.shinycore.picsayfree) or [Pho.to Lab](https://market.android.com/details?id=vsin.t16_funny_photo)) and add the text straight onto the picture.